# Selenium c# Multiple Options

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to use multiple options on my selenium project with Chrome as driver, but when i try to add headless + extension i got an error

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred   HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to
>   load:
>   chrome-extension://jmphljmgnagblkombahigniilhnbadca/_generated_background_page.html
>   from unknown error: page could not be found:
>   chrome-extension://jmphljmgnagblkombahigniilhnbadca/_generated_background_page.html
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120
>   (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.15063 x86_64)   Source=WebDriver   StackTrace:    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
>   desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
>   commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)    at
>   SeleniumTest.Form1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0() in
>   C:\Users\Ussagui\source\repos\SeleniumTest\SeleniumTest\Form1.cs:line
>   53    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

my code is:

```
var option = new ChromeOptions();

            option.AddArguments("--headless --disable-gpu");
            option.AddExtensions(@"EXTENSION PATH");

            var driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
            var action = new Actions(driver);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
```

if i use only the extension or argument it works.
How can i use both? Or i cant? 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. Though the arguments `--headless` and `--disable-gpu` are interrelated but are used for separate tasks. Hence we need to specify them separately.
2. Use optimal code block and comment/remove the debug/unused code. As `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);` doesn't need `WebDriver` instance to be casted so we need to comment/remove `var action = new Actions(driver);`
3. Your final code block will look like:

   ```
   var option = new ChromeOptions();
   option.AddArguments("--headless");
   option.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
   option.AddExtensions(@"EXTENSION PATH");
   var driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
   ```

Comment: Ow thanks mate! i will give a try when i get home.
About the  "var action = new Actions(driver);" i use it cause i got a "press enter" but i forget to post, sorry!

Btw whats the diference between "var option" and "ChromeOptions option" (using "var" or "ChromeOptions") Thanks